# visiblecells on a UICollectionView cannot invoke with no arguments

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

The documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618056-visiblecells

But I cannot seem to use this:
notesCollectionView.visibleCells() as! [NotesCollectionViewCell]

has an error:
"Cannot invoke 'visibleCells' with no arguments"

How can I get only the visibleCells in a UICollectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `visibleCells` is a variable, but you are using the function call syntax.
Removing the () should do the trick.

```
if let cells = notesCollectionView.visibleCells as? [NotesCollectionViewCell]
{
    // Do your magic here.
}
```